# Position Fixed CSS Not Working Fine

Tags: html, css

Sorry if i asking for stupid question, but i trying few hour not found the solution.
In my website i want to show MOBILE width search button in header for position fixed.

```css
.searchfixed {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:static;height:50px">
  <div class="searchfixed">My Button Search</div>
</div>
```

Why fixed position not working?

Comment: What happens when you use it?

Comment: if i adding div static position i my dekstop i got some blank space with height i create, but i not use static position, class "searchfixed" not show

Comment: Currently looking at your site and that css is not on there. And when I put those styles in manually it works fine.

Comment: Please create a fiddle that reproduces your problem

Comment: Hi @Nath how you mean put manually ?

Comment: @Swellar the problem is in my website css maybe, i have been try in fiddle it's work fine, i dont know what i miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on your site and the css is like this:

[image]

Thus, `position:fixed` isn't applied for some reason. If I manually add

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 99999; // without that it would be onder the content
```

then it works.[image]

Comment: Hi thanks mr @Boky its work for me, i'am forgot adding z-index: 99999;

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:static;` because default is `static` position, I have added height 500px; to check the position fixed, you can change it as you want.

```css
.searchfixed {
    display:block;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:500px">
  <div class="searchfixed">My Button Search</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank @Lokesh it work but it not good looking on my dekstop view

Comment: and when pass the body class it gone

Comment: Then make a fiddle and share code for the same so we can check it and help you

Comment: Hi Mr @Lokesh my resolved by mr boky, thanks for help :)

Comment: @LokeshGupta thanks a ton, this was the solution I was also loking for.Cheers mate.!!!